# Can DFT be real?

Tags: fourier-transform

If I have an input of real-valued matrix $A$ and take a [DFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform) of it, under which conditions the DFT of $A$ will be real, if possible at all? Thanks!

Comment: This occurs iff $x_n = x^*_{N - n - 1}$ for all $n$, where $x^*$ denotes the complex conjugate of $x$.  See [this table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discrete_Fourier_transform#Real_and_imaginary_part) on the page you linked.

Comment: So for ND DFT this same statement holds for each dimension independently, correct?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "ND" DFT. If you mean that you're taking the DFT of each column of $A$ separately (i.e. computing $F\cdot A$ where $F$ is the DFT matrix), then the statement should hold for each column separately.

Comment: ND: many dimensional. Wiki talks about vectors I wonder if the same stands for matrices.

Comment: I see now. If the function is simply periodic with the required period in each of its components, then yes: the same statement applies, and the method I describe correctly finds the dft.